# Array Conversion To List Error

Tags: java, eclipse

could someone explain to me what happens in the next lines of code and why it works?

```
Integer[] myray = {1,2,3,4,5};
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(myray));
l.add(6);
System.out.println(l);
```

The code above works fine. It converts an array to a list and then adds another element.
But the following code dose  not work

```
Integer[] myray = {1,2,3,4,5};
List<Integer> l = (Arrays.asList(myray));
l.add(6);
System.out.println(l);
```

The above code gives me the following error:
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException**
Can someone please tell me the difference between the two conversions and why only the first one works??
Thanks in advance

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Heights of coincidence ?  The answerer for the duplicate answered this question as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(myray)` returns a fixed sized `List` implementation (`java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`) backed by an array, so you can't add elements to it (or remove elements from it).

When you create a new `java.util.ArrayList` and pass to its constructor the fixed sized `List` you got from `Arrays.asList` (as you do in your first snippet), you get a normal `java.util.ArrayList` to which you can add elements.

Answer (score 1):

Because `asList` method from `Arrays` class gives you back a Immutable list where you cannot modify that. It is just  readable.

here are the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) for the same

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

Where as in the first case you are not using it directly and you creating a new list around it.

```
new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(myray));
```

When you do that internally the elements only gets copy and you get a regular instance of ArrayList.

Comment: `Arrays.asList` is not immutable, it is just fixed length (you can replace values in existing positions!).